# blank page in pagination Django 3.1

Tags: django, pagination, django-pagination

I implemented the Django pagination to slice the results of the search on my site.

```
# views.py
def search(request):

    # Keywords
    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']
        if keywords:
            title_list_control_valve = queryset_list.filter(title__icontains=keywords).order_by('title')  
            description_list_control_valve = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords).order_by('description').distinct('description')
           
            result_list_control_valves = list(chain(title_list_control_valve, 
                                 description_list_control_valve))
        
            result_list_control_valves_2 = list(dict.fromkeys(result_list_control_valves))

            paginator = Paginator(result_list_control_valves_2, 1)  
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            paged_queries = paginator.get_page(page)

            context = {
                'queries': paged_queries,
                }

            return render(request, 'pages/search.html', context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'pages/search.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'pages/search.html')
```

the URL of the site when showing search results is :

```
http://localhost:8000/pages/search/?keywords=something
```

It works perfectly fine on the first page only. From the second page on, it shows an empty page, and the URL of the site changes to:

```
http://localhost:8000/pages/search/?page=2
```

I link to other pages in the HTML as following:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    
    {% if queries.has_other_pages %}
    
      <ul class="pagination">
        {% if queries.has_previous %}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{queries.previous_page_number}} " class="page-link">&laquo;</a>
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link">&laquo;</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in queries.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if queries.number == i %}
            <li class="page-item active">
              <a class="page-link">{{i}}</a>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a href="?page={{i}} " class="page-link">{{i}}</a>
            </li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if queries.has_next %}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{queries.next_page_number}}" class="page-link">&raquo;</a>
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link">&raquo;</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>

    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The `?keywords=something` part of the URL goes away.

is it the problem?

how to make the other page's link work too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `keywords` to your `GET` params. For ex. `href="?page={{queries.previous_page_number}}&keywords={{request.GET.keywords}}"`